# Calculate (mean) sequence divergence for many sequences

Tags: bioinformatics, biopython, dna-sequence, sequence-alignment

I have ~13K sequences a 120 bases and I want to compare them to find things like conserved regions, a mean divergence between them or very diverging outliers.

The problem is, with this number of sequences the things I tried aren't doable.

So has anyone done something similar in  this size and can give me some hints how to achieve it? Or maybe just some tips where I should look for?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `dnadist` program of the [PHYLIP](http://evolution.genetics.washington.edu/phylip.html) package. You have some help in the Biopython library to deal with the Phylip alignment format [here](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.AlignIO-module.html.).